# Handling single quotation in Dynamic query

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have the following query where i am try to insert a record into my temp table using a dynamic query in my live application.

```
CREATE TABLE #AlertDealInfo1 (key varchar(50), Name varchar(50))
    declare @selectquery varchar(max)
    set @selectquery = 'select ''a'',''band'''
    insert #AlertDealInfo1 
    exec (@selectquery)

    select * from #AlertDealInfo1
    drop table #AlertDealInfo1
```

The above query works fine but if i want to insert a record with band's as the Name it says Unclosed quotation mark after the character string `''`.

```
CREATE TABLE #AlertDealInfo1 (deal_key varchar(50), alertName varchar(50))
declare @selectquery varchar(max)
set @selectquery = 'select ''a'',''band''s'''
insert #AlertDealInfo1 
exec (@selectquery)

select * from #AlertDealInfo1
drop table #AlertDealInfo1
```

What is the more elegant way to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
CREATE TABLE #AlertDealInfo1 (deal_key varchar(50), alertName varchar(50))
declare @selectquery varchar(max)
set @selectquery = 'select ''a'',''band''''s'''
insert #AlertDealInfo1 
exec (@selectquery)

select * from #AlertDealInfo1
drop table #AlertDealInfo1
```

you need a extra `''`

Answer (score 0):

I found this nice article on quotation marks:

http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/95670/

It really helped.